# Invocation target exception in my method toString()

Tags: java, android

I am novice in Java and Android. I need to send some text data from an one activity to the another activity. This is a method which send these text data to the another activity:

```
public void commandListener(View target) 
    {
        switch (target.getId()) 
        {
            case R.id.button1:
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(this, SubActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Send to the second activity", ++counter);
                intent.putExtra("Send person info", somePerson.toString());// INVOCATION TARGET EXCEPTION ON THIS STRING!!!
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                Intent intent2 = new Intent();
                intent2.setClass(this, ThirdActivity.class);
                intent2.putExtra("Send to the third activity", ++counter);
                startActivity(intent2);
                finish();
                break;
            default:
                counter = 0;
                finish();
                break;
        }
    }
```

In this code I get acception on intent.putExtra("Send person info", somePerson.toString()). somePerson.toString() initiates that exception. Where is my mistake?
SomePerson has a type Person
Here is an implementation of a Person:

```
public class Person implements Serializable 
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String firstName = "Vasya";
    private String lastName = "Pupkin";
    private Integer age = 58;
    private Integer phone = 02;

    @Override
    public String toString() 
    {
        return "Person [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName
                + ", age=" + age + "]";
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        firstName = name;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lName)
    {
        lastName = lName;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer personAge)
    {
        age = personAge;
    }

    public void setPhone(Integer personPhone)
    {
        phone = personPhone;
    }
}
```

This is a part of code from another activity, which accepts text data from another activity:

```
static int counter = 0;
    String personInfo;
    TextView counterView;
    TextView personInfoView;

    private static final String TAG = "myLogs";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

        counter = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("Send to the second activity");
        personInfo = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Send person info");
        counterView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        counterView.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
        personInfoView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        personInfoView.setText(personInfo);
        Log.d(TAG, "Counter value:");
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(counter));
    }
```

This is XML-code of activity which send data:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.switchactivity.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="string/this is the main activity" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="Counter" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:onClick="commandListener"
        android:text="Forward" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="commandListener"
        android:text="Third Activity" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="Second name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:text="Age" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:text="Phone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is XML-code of activity, which accepts text data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.switchactivity.SecondActivity$PlaceholderSub" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Counter" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text=" Second activity" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:onClick="commandListener2"
        android:text="Back" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I do not see where you declare "somePerson" in the first segment of code. Are you sure it is being set correctly before the method is declared?

Comment: `InvocationTargetException` is a wrapper around another exception, what was the original exception? (`ite.getCause()`).

Comment: Yes, somePerson is declared before the method. This is only type demonstration.

Comment: All of that code, and you didn't show the bit that matters.  Where and how do you initialise `somePerson`?

Comment: In my code this variable is declared as "Person somePerson". Her type Person inits her itself. It is showed in class Person.

Answer (score 0):

write all getter method for each variable in `Person` class and set each variable and use below line of code to send some text data from an one activity to the another activity

```
  intent.putExtra("Firstname", somePerson.getFirstName());
  intent.putExtra("LastName", somePerson.getLastName());
  intent.putExtra("Age", somePerson.getAge());
```

Comment: I might be missing something.  How does this address the problem?

Comment: May be, but why can I not use my method toString() to do this?

Answer (score 0):

remove `toString()` method from `somePerson.toString()` because u are implementing `Serializable` so there is no need of `toString ()` 
replace

```
   intent.putExtra("Send person info", somePerson.toString());
```

with

```
 intent.putExtra("Send person info", somePerson);
```

Comment: But I want to send data using this method, how can I do it without it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making the object parcelable instead of serializable since it is much quicker. Then you can just do a putExtra on the parcelable object.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html for reference on how to create parcelable objects.